# On click open id anchor inside dropdown menu on another page

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a link to an id tag wich is inside a dropdown menu and is placed on another page.

```html
<a href=index.html#test>link to id tag on another page</a>
```

The problem is when I click the link it goes to the right page but not shows the content because it is inside a collapsed dropdown bootstrap menu

```html
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
   <li><a class="chapter" href="01-primaria.html">
     <div class="img-menu">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="img/01-primaria.png">
     </div>
     <div class="titleChapter test">
      <strong>01.</strong>
      <br>
      Vuestro hijo está en Educación Primaria
      <small>Victoria Urzáiz Celigueta</small>
     </div>
   </a></li>
  </ul>
```

I need to deploy the right menu when the link is clicked (I will have more than one menu).
Any clue?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try calling a JS function that displays the intended page inside an iframe or a division when the items from the drop down list are chosen.
Eg: JS Function

```
function loadPage(){
document.getElementById("divisionID").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="01-primaria.html" ></object>';
}
```

HTML Page:
Create a division of the above name and leave it empty. So when your list item is clicked(onclick()) or when the selected item is changed (onchange()) call the JS function instead of referring to the page itself.

```
<li><a class="chapter" onchange="loadPage()">
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your relpy, but that's not what I'm trying to achieve. I will try to explain myself better: I need a link that points to an ID, when I click it it has to open the page it reffers in the id position (reloading the page as the default a tag behaviour). The problem is the target ID is inside a dropdown menu, for this reason when I click the link the right page loads, but the dropdown don't deploys and the right section is not showed.

Comment: I am no expert in Bootstrap modals, but I think researching a bit on Bootstrap Modal to implement your requirement would be quite helpful.<a class="chapter" id="chapter" href="01-primaria.html" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#indexModal">...</a>

Comment: Thanks again Nayantara! Modals, in this case, don't solve my problem at all, I need a simple a tag able to open a dropdown menu when loads the targeted page. As simple as this. ;)